# Dataset - Sample pdfs for text processing?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dataset, text-mining

I'm looking for a rather large amount of pdf files for testing my text processing program. Tried looking for an open site to get like some thousand pdfs, but wasn't able to find anything. I don't really know if that is the right place to ask (probably not) but maybe one has a good tip for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of PDFs?

Comment: Didn't really matter, but i've been served with a great answer already :)

Comment: Good question, but it could probably be moved to [OpenData SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GitHub repo with ~1,000 pdfs is [here](https://github.com/tpn/pdfs).

Another GitHub repo has a corpus of pdf examples, including [edge-cases](https://github.com/openpreserve/format-corpus/tree/master/pdfCabinetOfHorrors), is [here](https://github.com/openpreserve/format-corpus).

Comment: Thanks, the first one fits perfectly. 

Edge-cases is not really what I'm targeting yet, but i will definetly keep that in mind